# Hyper link is not working with embed tag in IE or Chrome

Tags: css, html, hyperlink, cross-browser

```
<param id="movie" name="movie" value='<%= Me.ResolveUrl(Me.BannerPath)%>'> 

    <a  href='http://<%= BannerTargetUrl%>' target="_blank">

           <embed  wmode="transparent" src='<%= Me.ResolveUrl(Me.BannerPath)%>' align="middle" Width="468px" Height="60px" />

    </a>
```

In This code  tag link work Properly in Mozilla but Hyper link is not working in IE or Chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<embed>` tag is a block level element and `<a>` tag is an inline element. Try giving the HTML 5 Doctype:

```
<!doctype html>
```

And give block display for `<a>`:

```
a {display: block;}
```

Comment: Did you give `a {display: block;}`?

Comment: Okay nice. What is the IE version?

Comment: @HarishPatel Yeah thats good. :) Can you post the full HTML Code? Not the source one. :) The one rendered to browser.

Comment: Just post the content from `<a>`, `<embed>` tags.

Comment: Dude, seriously! Can you post the **rendered HTML**? Not the source code. You are having something like `<%= ... %>` stuff, which are Java stuff...